# .NET core WebAPI Apps on Ubuntu

Tags: .net, webapi

Can I develop .NET core WebAPI Apps in Windows and directly deploy on Ubuntu server. Do I need to compile my solution & projects targeting the Linux environment?

`Note, I understand, .NET Core SDK runtime has to be installed in Ubuntu server`.

Thanks
SM

Comment: You can. You have to compile targeting specific platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes definitely you can do that. That's the main purpose of .Net Core.

> Do I need to compile my solution & projects targeting the Linux environment?

Yes, you have to compile your solution and tell the compiler your run time like:

`dotnet build -r linux-x64`

You can find more info from official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/) from Microsoft. They are very detailed and sophisticated.